# Floor map for Shinken

Tags: monitoring, shinken

It seems that Shinken supports placing devices on a Google Map out of the box, however, I am looking for a more granular solution to visualise devices inside of a building.

Is there a way to implement a device assignment to a location on an image (floor plan) similarly to what is done in the World Map plugin?

References:

[Shinken World map plugin](https://github.com/shinken-monitoring/mod-webui/wiki/Configuration---Worldmap)

Answer (score 0):

I visualize my monitoring with Pandora FMS (that also monitors my structure) and his maps and consoles are pretty nice. They are completly customizable even with my own images, so it's a good solution. Take a look on their site: https://pandorafms.com/monitoring-solutions/server-monitoring/